# How to fix Xamarin.Forms iOS color disparity on TitleBar image VS TitleBar background when Android does not have this issue

Tags: xamarin.forms, view, colors, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have an Image (that is the size of a banner) that has a background color `#F6D401` [image] and needs to go to TopBar, for branding.

in App.xaml I set:

```
<Application.Resources>    
    <ResourceDictionary>    
        <Color x:Key="Primary">#f6d401</Color>    
        <Color x:Key="TextColor">#5a5a5a</Color>
```

Then in AppShell.xaml

```
    <Shell.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
            <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
```

Then on pages:

```
    <Shell.TitleView>
    <Image
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
        Source="logo.png"  />
</Shell.TitleView>
```

On Android I get a background banner and all the colors the same color, which is exactly what I want and what is expected.

[image]

on iOS, however, colors do not seem to match

[image]

I am assuming there is a default setting on iOS somewhere that is doing this, that needs to be changed.

**How do I make banner and icon colors to match?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add   `UINavigationBar.Appearance.Translucent = false;` to `AppDelegate.cs`

```
 public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
       
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.Translucent = false;
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
    }
```

Here is running screenshot.

[image]